# Identity Insert Problem

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert, identity

I am trying to run this script:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Message ON
INSERT INTO dbo.Message
SELECT (Values I want to insert)
```

and when I do I still get the error
*An explicit value for the identity column in table 'dbo.Message' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to your error is "when a column list is used". You want:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Message ON
INSERT INTO dbo.Message (column1, column2, ...) -- Added column list here
SELECT (Values I want to insert)
```

Comment: Remember: SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Message OFF !

Answer (score 2):

You need to do just as the error message says.  Format your code like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Message
(col1, col2, col3, col4)
SELECT Col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM OtherTable
```

You need the list of fields after the `INSERT` line, and you need to specify the field names in your `SELECT` - `SELECT *` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention all the columns Name in both Insert Statement and in select clause.
Some thing like this.

Insert Into tbl
(
[col1],
[col2]
)
SELECT 
[col1],
[col2]